# Drag and drop to change order in database

Tags: php, javascript

There is probably a very simple solution to this but I just haven't been able to think it through.

I'm working an image gallery admin page. I'm using a drag and drop interface so the user can manage the order and content of their gallery.

So far the drag and drop works perfect. When I drag one image and drop it on another they swap places. Just like magic.

Being a complete noob I was pretty happy to get that far.

Here is where I've been stuck for days now. I'm trying to figure out a way to link the images to their new positions so I can submit that information to the database.

I was thinking there could be a way to get javascript to create variables named to match the columns and assign the image ID to it that occupies its position. I haven't figured out how to do that yet.

I'm open to other ideas too.

Here is my PHP:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "
SELECT *
FROM `gallery`
WHERE `order`") or die(mysqli_error());

$i = 0;
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $i++;
    echo "<div id=columns>";
    echo "<div class='column' id='c".$i."'><header>" . $i . "</header>";
    echo "<div class='columncontent' draggable='true'><img src='../gallery/gimages/" . $row['file'] . "' width='75px' title='" .$row['name']. "' id='i" .$row['id']. "'><br>" . $row['name'] . "</div></div></div>";
    }
```

Here is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var dragSrcEl = null;

function handleDragStart(e) {

    dragSrcEl = this;

    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', this.innerHTML);
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', this.innerHTML);
    }

    var cols = document.querySelectorAll('#columns .columncontent');
    [].forEach.call(cols, function(col) {
    col.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
    });

function handleDragOver(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    }

    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move'; 

    return false;
    }

function handleDragEnter(e) {
    this.classList.add('over');
    }

function handleDragLeave(e) {
    this.classList.remove('over');
    }

function handleDrop(e) {

    if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    }

    if (dragSrcEl != this) {
    dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
    }

    return false;
    }

function handleDragEnd(e) {

    [].forEach.call(cols, function (col) {
    col.classList.remove('over');
    });
    }

    var cols = document.querySelectorAll('#columns .columncontent');
    [].forEach.call(cols, function(col) {
    col.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
    col.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false)
    col.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
    col.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
    col.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
    col.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
    });

</script>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does your table structure look like? Is there an ID field?

Comment: Warning: don't try to reinvent the wheel ;-) Have a look at this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633341/jquery-ui-sortable-then-write-order-into-a-database (for example)

Comment: For starters, where do you explicitly _set_ the ordering in the first place?  Currently you're displaying the records in whatever order they are returned from the database.  If you want to explicitly order them then you'll need a column to hold that ordering (an integer), populate that column with a sort order when adding a record (and update all legacy records), order your SELECT query to use that column, and update that column's values any time the sort order changes (which would probably be in an AJAX call form the drop event in the JavaScript).

Comment: David - The ordering is set by "order" column of my database. It just so happens that currently it's the same order as the id column. The id column is my primary index. The order column is what I intend to be able to edit.

Comment: @Pieter - That looks like a great solution. Thanks for that. Kind of a kick in the balls to start over though after working on this for weeks. I guess I better get used to it if I'm going to keep doing this stuff.