# How to send jQuery Sortable (serialized) List to new page?

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have 2 lists and I'm using jQuery sortables to organize them...one is a list of elements in their original order and the other is a container for the newly sorted list of these elements. I'd like to send this new list order to the next page (using the post method ($.post?)), but so far have been unable to get this to work.

Thanks to this post: [jQuery UI Sortable, then write order into a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633341/jquery-ui-sortable-then-write-order-into-a-database) I've been able to see the array (of the new order) on my current page (Query String: item[]=3&item[]=1&item[]=2&item[]=4), but when I attempt to post it to the next page, my array is empty..."array(0) { }".

I'm very new to jQuery and PHP, and am sure I'm missing something obvious...

Example of lists:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<body>
<h1>Lists</h1>
<ul id="list2" class="droptrue">
</ul>
<ul id="list1" class="droptrue">
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="item-1"><button>Element 1</button></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="item-2"><button>Element 2</button></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="item-3"><button>Element 3</button></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="item-4"><button>Element 4</button></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="item-5"><button>Element 5</button></li>
</ul>
<br style="clear: both;" />
Query String <div></div><br>

  <button id="goto">continue</button>
</body>
```

Example script:

```
    $(function() {
    $( "ul.droptrue" ).sortable({
      connectWith: "ul"
     });
    $( "ul" ).sortable({
     handle: 'button',
     cancel: ''
     })
    $( "#list1, #list2" ).disableSelection();
     });
    $(function() {
    $( "button" )
      .button()
      .click(function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
     });
    $('#goto').button().click(function(event){
      document.location.href='three.php';
      })
     });
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#list2').sortable({
      stop: function (event, ui) {
      var listdata = $(this).sortable('serialize');
      $('div').text(listdata);
      $.post( "three.php", listdata );
        }
      });
    });
```

CSS:

```
    #list1, #list2 { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; float: left; margin-right: 100px; background: #eee; padding: 5px; width: 250px; height: 500px;}
    #list2 li button, #list1 li button{ margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-size: 10px; width: 250px; height: 25px;}
```

PHP (on next page - "three.php"):

```
    var_dump($_POST) //produces an empty array "array(0) { }"

    //once I can get the array to the next page, I would like to iterate through it
    //and insert it into a database table
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_POST['item'] as $value) {
    //insert into table column where [id] = $value
    $i++;
    }
```

Comment: You need your PHP code to re-build the HTML based on your data. Your PHP code is not shown, but is required to answer this question.

Comment: Since I'm having trouble getting the array to appear on the next page, I haven't gotten very far with my PHP plans. This is more than likely the source of my problem, any thoughts on where to go from here?