# How to change what jquery ui sortable return?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a CMS that let my users to sort menu by jquery ui sortable.

**What does jquery ui return?**

I used this code:

*JavaScript:*

```
$( "#menuUl" ).sortable({
    update: function (event, ui) {
        var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
        console.log(data);
     }
})
```

html:

```
echo '<ul id="menuUl">';
    $i=0;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_select_menu)){
        $i++;
        echo '<li name="asdsad" id="li-'.$row['menu_id'].'" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>'.$row['title'].'<input type="hidden" value="" id="hidden-'.$row['menu_id'].'" class="hiddenClass" name="id['.$row['menu_id'].']"/></li>
        ';    
    }
    echo '</ul>';
```

---

This is what javascript says :

> li[]=2&li[]=1&li[]=3&li[]=4&li[]=5&li[]=6&li[]=7&li[]=8&li[]=9&li[]=10&li[]=11&li[]=12&li[]=13&li[]=14

I need to know which li has what number. 
**like this:**

> li[1]=2&li[2]=1&li[3]=3&li[4]=4&li[5]=5&li[6]=6&li[7]=7&li[8]=8&li[9]=9&li[10]=10&li[11]=11&li[12]=12&li[13]=13&li[14]=14

my other question is this: **Can I change what serialize return, for example serialize return li[]=1, but I need to say li[1]=1**

Comment: @ArunPJohny This is my html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some way to doing this, I think you should use **serialize**, and then send it by Ajax to your server side page.

This is a good answer for you [write order into database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633341/jquery-ui-sortable-then-write-order-into-a-database)

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box: no, you can't do this. `sortable.serialize()` returns a string formatted according to the spec in [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/). The closest approach to doing it out of the box would be with `sortable.toArray()` with `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`.

As for doing it manualy, since this is all in order, and only contains `li`s, converting it to the format you say you want wouldn't be difficult:

```
var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
var i = 0;
while(data.indexOf("li[]") !== -1) {
    data = data.replace(/li\[\]/, "li[" + (i++) + "]");
}
```

This will convert your first string to

```
li[0]=2&li[1]=1&li[2]=3&li[3]=4&li[4]=5&li[5]=6&li[6]=7&li[7]=8&li[8]=9&li[9]=10&li[10]=11&li[11]=12&li[12]=13&li[13]=14
```

---

Keep in mind you'll need to maintain this yourself, and it's only for the case where you absolutely need to preserve array indices.