# Jquery / Jquery UI sortable having issues to GET data with php

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

First all i'm not familiar of jquery, if it's a noob question forgive me.
I have a web app and trying to use `jQuery sortable` function to drag drop data table to change `order_id` on mysql via `php`.

If i use `jquery 1.11.1` and `jquery ui 1.10.3` my function doesn't send data to my php file.

But if i use `jquery 1.3.2` and `jquery ui 1.7.2` my function send data and it gives following success message on console:

`XHR finished loading: GET"http://localhost/.../ArticlesSort.php?listItem[]=2&listItem[]…tItem[]=4&listItem[]=5&listItem[]=6&listItem[]=7&listItem[]=8&listItem[]=9"`

My jquery function looks like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#test-list").sortable({ 
        handle : '.handle', 
        update : function () { 
            var order = $('#test-list').sortable('serialize'); 
            $("#info").load("ArticlesSort.php?"+order); 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

What am i missing?
Any help will greatly appricated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer on [jQuery UI Sortable, then write order into a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633341/) question's related answer. And it worked.
I'm pasting my final code here if someone will have same issue to find solution easily:

```
$("#test-list").sortable({ 
        handle : '.handle', 
        update : function () { 
            var order = $('#test-list').sortable('serialize'); 
            $.ajax({
                data: order,
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'ArticlesSort.php?'+order,
            });
        } 
});
```

Comment: i reckon the data attribute is not needed there as you are appending the same value in URL....

Comment: And also you can mark your own answer as **THE ANSWER**