# How to make JQuery UI Sortable mobile friendly (work on touch devices)?

Tags: jquery, sorting, mobile, touch, jquery-ui-sortable

Here is good solution of sorting elements using jQuery: [jQuery UI Sortable, then write order into a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633341/jquery-ui-sortable-then-write-order-into-a-database)

```
$('#element').sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    update: function (event, ui) {
        var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');

        // POST to server using $.post or $.ajax
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/your/url/here'
        });
    }
});
```

But how change the code to make it mobile friendly? Sorting on the touch screens don't work at all.

Comment: This should do it: http://touchpunch.furf.com